# $a*x^2+b*x+c $ with integer a,b,c can always be factored with integer (!) coefficients if its discriminant is not irrational?

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

Does this assertion really hold?

My math teacher said so.

I cannot give a counterexample so far but I doubt the assertion.

Comment: $x^2+x-1$ does not work

Comment: I think you mean to say, "If the discriminant is a perfect square."

Comment: **Maybe a better way to state it.**  Consider a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ with integer coefficients.  If it can be factored using rational coefficients, then in fact it can be factored using integer coefficients.

Comment: @GEdgar I would accept it as answer, I feel you are right but I don't understand - factorization is unique, there can't be two (different?) factorizations with therefore (different?) coefficients? how (x-1/2)(x+3) can be a factorization with integer coefficients? If ax^2+bx+c = (x-1/2)(x+3) = (x-integer1)(x-integer2) ?

Comment: $(x-1/2)(x+3)$ cannot be factored with integer coefficients.  But (multiplying it out) it does not have integer coefficients to start with, so we do not expect it.

Answer (score 0):

How about $x^{2}+1$? This satisfies the hypothesis, doesn't it? You cannot factor this even in $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ with integer coefficients $a,b,c$.
The zeros are
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
If the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ is an nonnegative integer which is a square, i.e., $D=d^2$ for some nonnegative integer $d$, then 
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm d}{2a}.$$
The zeros are integral if $2a$ divides $-b\pm d$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ with integer coefficients $a,b,c$.
The zeros are
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
If the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ is an nonnegative integer which is a square, i.e., $D=d^2$ for some integer $d$, then 
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm d}{2a}.$$
The zeros are integral if $2a$ divides $-b\pm d$.